# How to specify radio buttons in baseFieldDefinitions?

Tags: 8, entities

In the baseFieldDefinitions method of my custom entity, I see I can provide a checkbox list with code like...

```
$fields['my_field'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create("list_string")
      ->setSetting('allowed_values', $$my_options)
      ->setLabel('My Field')
      ->setRequired(FALSE)
      ->setCardinality(-1)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'options_buttons',
        'weight' => 5
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

But how would I specify radio buttons so the user can make only one selection from the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The radios/checkboxes are displayed based on the field's ***cardinality***:

- If the field can store ***more than one*** (e.g., unlimited: `->setCardinality(-1)`, or 2,3,etc. `->setCardinality(2)`, `->setCardinality(3)`, etc.), it will be displayed as ***checkboxes***.
- If the field can store ***only one*** (i.e. `->setCardinality(1)`), it will be displayed as ***radio buttons***.